# Is there a mathematical term for the number of digits of an integer?

Tags: integers

Magnitude would be fitting, but is used to mean absolute value.

Is there any singular term used to describe the number of digits in an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is just called the "length" or the "number of digits".  Note that this depends on the base the number is represented in, the same number will have different lengths in different bases.  A simple formula is given by $\lfloor \log_b n \rfloor +1$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Specifically, consider $b=n=10$.